# Gaussian Process regression hyparameter optimisation using python Grid search

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, hyperparameters, gaussian-process

I am started learning Gaussian regression using Sklearn library using my own data points as given below. though I got the result it is inaccurate because I did not do hyperparameter optimisation. I did some couple of google search and written `gridsearch`code. But the code is not running as expected.  I don't know where I made my mistake, please help and thanks in advance.

The sample of input and output data is given as follows

```
X_tr= [10.8204  7.67418 7.83013 8.30996 8.1567  6.94831 14.8673 7.69338 7.67702 12.7542 11.847] 
y_tr= [1965.21  854.386 909.126 1094.06 1012.6  607.299 2294.55 866.316 822.948 2255.32 2124.67]
X_te= [7.62022  13.1943 7.76752 8.36949 7.86459 7.16032 12.7035 8.99822 6.32853 9.22345 11.4751]
```

`X_tr, y_tr` and `X_te` are the training data points and are reshape values and have a type of 'Array of float64'

Here my grid search code

```
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

                tuned_parameters = [{'kernel': ['rbf'], 'gamma': [1e-3, 1e-4],   
                     'C': [1, 10, 100, 1000]},
                    {'kernel': ['linear'], 'C': [1, 10, 100, 1000]}]

scores = ['precision', 'recall']

for score in scores:
    print("# Tuning hyper-parameters for %s" % score)
    print()

    clf = GridSearchCV(
        gp(), tuned_parameters, scoring='%s_macro' % score
    )
    clf.fit(X_tr, y_tr)
```

Here is a sample of my code without hyperparameter optimisation:

```
import sklearn.gaussian_process as gp
kernel = gp.kernels.ConstantKernel(1.0, (1e-1, 1e3)) * gp.kernels.RBF(10.0, (1e-3, 1e3))
model = gp.GaussianProcessRegressor(kernel=kernel, n_restarts_optimizer=10, alpha=0.1, normalize_y=True)

X_tr=np.array([X_tr])
X_te=np.array([X_te])
y_tr=np.array([y_tr])

model.fit(X_tr, y_tr)
params = model.kernel_.get_params()
X_te = X_te.reshape(-1,1)
y_pred, std = model.predict(X_te, return_std=True)
```

Comment: Hi. Can you post the error message?

Comment: This is the error I am getting. 'Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-26-6bb77b0a3f86>", line 6, in <module>
    gp(), tuned_parameters, scoring='%s_macro' % score

TypeError: 'module' object is not callable'

Comment: So it looks like the error is at the `gp()` line. The `scoring` parameter should be one from those: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#scoring-parameter and could you elaborate what the `% score` term purpose is? It doesn't look like is needed.

Comment: 'scoring' I used to see optimised parameter accuracy which I found it from this example, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35046129/python-gaussian-process-regression-and-gridsearchcv.

Answer (score 5):

There were a few issues in that code snippet you provided, the one below is a working example:

```
from sklearn.gaussian_process import GaussianProcessRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.gaussian_process.kernels import RBF, DotProduct
import numpy as np

X_tr = np.array([10.8204, 7.67418, 7.83013, 8.30996, 8.1567, 6.94831, 14.8673, 7.69338, 7.67702, 12.7542, 11.847])
y_tr = np.array([1965.21, 854.386, 909.126, 1094.06, 1012.6, 607.299, 2294.55, 866.316, 822.948, 2255.32, 2124.67])
X_te = np.array([7.62022, 13.1943, 7.76752, 8.36949, 7.86459, 7.16032, 12.7035, 8.99822, 6.32853, 9.22345, 11.4751])


param_grid = [{
    "alpha":  [1e-2, 1e-3],
    "kernel": [RBF(l) for l in np.logspace(-1, 1, 2)]
}, {
    "alpha":  [1e-2, 1e-3],
    "kernel": [DotProduct(sigma_0) for sigma_0 in np.logspace(-1, 1, 2)]
}]

# scores for regression
scores = ['explained_variance', 'r2']

gp = GaussianProcessRegressor()
for score in scores:
    print("# Tuning hyper-parameters for %s" % score)
    print()

    clf = GridSearchCV(estimator=gp, param_grid=param_grid, cv=4,
                       scoring='%s' % score)
    clf.fit(X_tr.reshape(-1, 1), y_tr)
    print(clf.best_params_)
```

I would like to break it down now  in order to provide some explanation. The first part is data. You will need more data (presumably you only gave a sample here) but you will also need to [rescale](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html) it for the gaussian process to work efficiently.

The second part is the `param_grid`. The parameter grid can be a dictionary or a list of dictionaries. I used a list of dictionaries as it appears that you are interested in testing the performance of different kernels. The granularity of the parameter grid is very low when you add more data I would recommend to increase the granularity by adding more test variables for `alpha` and increasing the `np.logpspace` steps as well as bounds.

The third part is the scores to test. In the snippet above you had scores for classification algorithms I used [scores](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html) for regression as you are interested in regression.

The fourth part runs the model. It should print the best parameters for each score. I couldn't get any reliable fits because the dataset was really limited. Note the reshape of the `X_tr` input as it's one-dimensional.